# Ensuring thread safe operations for a list that is value in a dictionary

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

I have a `Dictionary<object1, List<object2>` (a abstractisation I made for my structure, which is a little more complex).

The lists inside the dictionary are initialized in a non-parallel context, but adding new elements to the list needs a thread safe method. Removing items will not occure (the dictionary object will be disposed at the end of transactions).
Also, the key-value pairs are added only at initialisation, so no keys are added or removed from the dictionary during work, only the values are updated.

I can't use concurent collections, I'm stuck in an old .NET Framework.

At first I locked the whole dictionary with a `ReadWriteSlimlock`. Well, this was very bad performance wise. There are many adding operations happening and they just wait for another. Locking only each list is a far better solution, because at least I'm doing stuff in parallel for each key.
Also, the adding operation are not simple `list.Add(object2)`, some other complex operations need to occur in the thread safe area at adding.

But I don't know what is the best way to implement it:

1. `lock(dictionary.Value)` ?
2. Using a dictionary of `ReadWriteSlimlock` (one for each key)?
3. Any other better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution could be to implement you concurent `List<object>` class.
Something like:

```
public class ConcurentList {
    private object sync = new object(); 
    private List<object> realList = new List<object>(); 


    public void Add(object o) {
        lock(sync){
           realList.Add(o);
        }
    }   

    /** ADD OTHERE METHODS IMPEMENTATION IF NEED **/

}
```

and in dictionary have:

```
Dictionary<object1, ConcurentList>
```

Why *encapsulate* and and not extend `List<object>`, is cause `Add` method is not virtual, so the only way you can "override" it, is using `new` keyword, which is guranteed to be called *only* if used on the *exactly same type*, which means if you cast list to the base, it won't be called, so hole architecture will fail.

By encapsulating, you give to the caller only one method, where you control everything.

Don't know if this solution fits your needs, but hope it gives you some hints on how possibly  manage stuff.

Comment: Since adding is my actual problem, I really like the encapsulation ideea. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

Why not write your own concurrent thread safe variants of `Dictionary<>` and `List<>`? It's what I've done for .NET 2.

Personally I opted for the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` because it allows you to control locking based on access pattern and for the most part my lists were being read from a lot more that being wrote to.

However, you are doing a lot of adding so you might want to try both (`lock` and `ReaderWriterLockSlim`) and see which performs better.

Comment: At some point `ReaderWriterLockSlim` seemed strange to use in this situation (I am writing parallel, and writing only once, at the end). I think of `ReaderWriterLockSlim` as appropiate for situations with far more reading involved. In the end I guess that I will implement some ideas an compare them, since performance is a great issue in this question.

Comment: Yes, as I understood it it's aimed mainly where there's a read/write need and there's a lot of read contention.

Answer (score 1):

If reading from lists happens concurrently with writing, constructing a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` object for each dictionary entry would be an optimal solution, because multiple readers would be able to proceed concurrently on the same list. It is only marginally harder than using `lock(key)`, and it has a potential of improving performance in cases when a small number of lists is read more often than other lists.

If you go the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` route, it is a good idea to wrap the list and a lock in a single class, rather than creating a separate dictionary just for the reader writer locks:

```
class LockableList {
    public ReaderWriterLockSlim RwLock {get;private set;}
    public List<object2> Data {get;private set;}
    public LockableList() {
        RwLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
        Data = new List<object2>();
    }
}
...
Dictionary<object1,LockableList> myDictionary;
```

Combining the list and the look would let you look up the dictionary entry once, lock it for reading or for writing as appropriate, and do the work with the associated list.

Comment: Your idea of wrapping the list and lock is great! Worth to take into consideration not only in this case.